# When to 'return' in an Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c, methods, return

Just a quick question. I was just wandering whether or not, I still have to "return;" even in a void function?

At the moment, even in methods which are not returning a variable/etc... I still have "return" at the end of the method.

So do I still need this? Because I swear without it, it does NOT return to where it was called from.

EG:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Run other setup code....

    // Run method 1.
    [self method_01];

    // Run next bit of code....
}

-(void)method_01 {

     // Run code....

     return;
}
```

Do I still have to do it like the above example?

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: you can return at any time from a function... just make sure it is the correct type, and a void returning function just returns with no value.

Comment: @Wain I think the issue I'm having is with an asynchronous network request. It does't return when I want it to. But now I am starting to learn more about how it works and how its meant to be a background process, so yeah.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff *Asynchronous*, huh?  An asynchronous method will return to the caller immediately, even long before it is done doing the actual work on some other thread/queue.   You'll want to pass in a completion block that the asynchronous method will call when it is done (which will be after the method already returned).

Comment: @bbum Yes thanks. That was part of the problem, I wasn't using the completion block. Thanks all fixed now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the return is at the end of the method, it doesn't make any difference.

```
-(void) doSomethingWithX:(int) X
{
     ..........................
     ........some Code.........
     ..........................

     return ;
 }
```

The control would reach the caller one the method execution completes. Marking a return does the same.

However in a condition like below,

```
-(void) doSomethingWithX:(int) X
{
     if(X>10)
     {
          return;
     }

     ..........................
     ........some Code.........
     ..........................
 }
```

The `some code` will not be executed if your X value is greater than 10. So, by default control return to the caller at the end of method. Use return if you want to force a return to caller in between the method execution.

Comment: Thanks, has the best example too. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You do not. The method will return to its previous point of execution once it reaches the end of the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call return in methods that are defined with `void` and thus do not return a value.

There are times when you would want to call `return` in such methods, such as if you want to exit out of the method without executing the remaining code, if a particular condition is met:

```
if (iHaveDeterminedIAmFinished) {
    return;
}

... // code that would otherwise execute.
```

Other than this, it would be bad practice to routinely include `return` at the end of every method. Every Objective-C method returns without exception, if it reaches the end of the method without a previous `return`. Therefore, this practice would not be more clear to a reader who has any familiarity with Objective-C. Indeed, it would likely confuse other developers reading your code who would be left wondering what the intention was. It would be likely to appear like something had been omitted from the end of the method, since there would be no reason for including this return otherwise. In short, I suggest it would be bad practice to include unnecessary `return` calls at the end of methods.

> Because I swear without it, it does NOT return to where it was called from.

Something else is going on here. You may well need to figure out what it is, but it is not correct that the absence of `return` calls would prevent a return to the point of execution. Either it is returning, and you're not realising it for some reason, or something else is happening in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way.  It should return automatically without an explicit return.

Comment: If I continue to add an explicit return, is that considered a bad practice? Because for me, it makes the program more clear?

Comment: Every Objective-C method returns without exception, if it reaches the end of the method without a previous `return`. Therefore, it is not more clear to a reader who has any familiarity with Objective-C. Indeed, it would confuse other developers who would be left wondering what the intention was as it would be unclear whether something had been omitted from the method, since there would be no reason for including it otherwise. In short, it would be bad practice to include this in my view.

Comment: I've now added the core of my comment above to my original answer.